# datasnap pass multiple datasets from server to client and vice versa

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I am new in datasnap technology. I would like to develop a client server app over internet. In order to avoid many server calls I would like to know how can i transfer multiple datasets from server to client upon client request  , using one call and then after making changes in the client , to transfer multiple deltas of the clientdatasets from client to sever using one call method. Thank you very much﻿

Comment: If the data are in a master/detail relationship Datasnap can do it automatically (just it will move details with their master records - not the whole dataset, but that makes sense).
If they are "uncorrelated" datasets, it can't. If you need to control the transactions, you can't rely on Datasnap default management - you need to handle that situation yourself. IMHO more than one call once the connection is established won't slow down the connection much - if you like you cold extract the deltas and send them at once, but you're going to rewrite a lot of Datasnap default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard behaviour of DataSnap. But if you really need this functionality you can and will have to write it yourself.

On a side note: why are you worried with many server calls? Are you on a limited bandwith connection?

Comment: The problem actually is when I make changes on the client (in 2 datasets) and want to move them back to the server and I want to have the StartTransaction and commit methods to the server , in which server in the same transaction may have other business logic as well with extra datasets not needed in the client. That's why I need to move all the datasets changed in the client using a server call method to the server and apply all the business logic within a transaction in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Marco Cantu blogged about using FireDAC and getting datasets from a DataSnap server - "using FireDACJSONReflect for DataSnap" - article at 
[delphi_xe5_update2_datasnap_firedac](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_xe5_update2_datasnap_firedac.html)

Comment: Thank you very match. It seems an interesting blog. I will have a look at it.